# How to make a public repo with forks into a private repo without breaking forks or PRs?

Tags: github, private, public, git-fork, github-organizations

I have:

A public repo with public forks.  Everyone that has forked is in my "Organization," many have made pull requests.

I want:

That repo to be private, and for the forks to remain intact, ideally with each member who forked having the option to keep theirs public or also make it private.  If I can't do that then I want to make them all private.

Yes I've read [this](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#changing-a-public-repository-to-a-private-repository) and [this](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-people-to-fork-private-repositories-in-your-organization/) .... and am willing to settle for the forks continuing to exist as independent repos, but just wondered if anyone had encountered this before.

Comment: Note: I am aware that if the repo is created privately in the organization, you can fork and make PRs which all remain private to the organization.  I'm specifically interested in ones that were initially created as public.

Comment: I would just test with a dummy repo that is initially public, fork it, make some changes (PR), etc... Then change it to private and see what happens...

Comment: Yea that's a good call, and I did do that, and it seems I can preserve everything but the forks' links. But the PRs and their comments remain intact, so I'm certainly prepared to just settle for that, if it's not possible to keep those links intact.

Comment: It makes sense that the forks wouldn't link as it is private and they are public... Have you tried to change the fork to private and see if the link returns or works?